# Find equivalent expression without the summation symbol

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am trying to teach myself, but I am confused on one question. It says "for the following summation, give an equivalent equation without the summation:  $\sum_{i=5}^n i$

I am not to sure how to find this. Please show me the steps on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: $1+2+3+4+5=15$.

Comment: $$\ln\prod_{i=5}^ne^i$$ is an equivalent expression with no summation symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This summation is similar to the well-known formula

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

This suggests three approaches to the problem you might try.

### Approach 1

The methods used to derive the identity above should also work to derive an identity for the summation you're interested in.

### Approach 2

Do some experimentation to *guess* at what identity might be true; it probably looks similar to the identity above. If you find the right formula, then the methods used to verify the identity above should also work to verify the formula you guessed.

### Approach 3

Find an identity relating the summation you're interested in to the summation above. Then you can invoke the identity above to get an identity for your summation.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i=5}^n i = 5 + 6 + 7 + ... + n.$

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Try to use arithmetic series or

$$\sum_{i=5}^n i = \sum_{i=1}^n i- \sum_{i=1}^4 i$$

Comment: $ \dfrac{n+5}{2} * (n-5+1) $